# Another way to set OnScrollListener

Tags: android, scroll, uiscrollview, scrollview

**About task.** 
I worked with own CustomView that extends from HorizontalScrollView. In other words, that is some realization Adapter, for adding another view elements. This CustomView animate adding and deleting elements. And! Should animate views when scrolling.

**Other information.** 
There are works algorithms to animate Views from and to center. Ex. increase view scale, when scrolling it to center and decrease, when scrolling from center.

**Problem.** 
I had only one problem with animation, when scrolling. When user scroll, and interface OnScrollView is trigger I animate view (which is visible) using ObjectAnimator. I attached different implementation of  OnScrollListener, that didn't work for me(list below). Actually, when user scroll - ScrollView first of all scroll all element, and only after that - call method OnScroll. So, as a result animation work with some delay. And this delay is more manifest, when scrolling is faster.

**Note.** Ex. of work same CustomView in native Android and IOS alarms. When you choosing time, and scrolling list of numbers they are transformed, changing angle. So as a result, you scrolling it, like a drum.

I hope enough information. Cheers!

```
// Some different onScrollListeners, that didn't 
// work for me (worked with delay).

// 1
getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListenernew OnScrollChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            // Notify and animate view using - this.getScrollX();
        }
    });


// 2

  @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            // Notify and animate view using - this.getScrollX();
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }


// 3

@Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldX, int oldY) {
        super.onScrollChanged(x, y, oldX, oldY);

        // Notify and animate view using - this.getScrollX();
    }
```

.

.

.

.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done this task with simplest solution. As you can see, when ScrollView state is scrolling - I just start animation, which worked without attaching to scroll position. So solution of this task , its using **simple scale transformation** until we scrolling, and not animation!

As a result, i will publish this work as new type of list adapters - AnimatedViewPager in few weeks. Me on Github, GensaGames.